# Is bijection implied by mutual injection?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose $f : A \to B$ is one-to-one, and there is another function $g : B \to A$ which is also one-to-one. We don’t assume anything in particular about the relationship between $f$ and $g$. Are $f$ and $g$ necessarily bijections?

Comment: I don't think so, no; maybe as long as they're finite/countable. But you can always use them to construct a bijection. See the Schröder-Bernstein theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem and its proof

Comment: If you want an example... let $A=B=\Bbb N$ and for each $n\in \Bbb N$ let $f(n)=g(n)=2n$.  These are clearly both injections (*as if $2a=2b$ then necessarily $a=b$*) yet neither are a surjection (*there is no natural number $n$ such that $2n = 3$ for instance*).

Comment: Another example is the inclusion of $\mathbb{R}^+$ into $\mathbb{R}$. Clearly this map is injective but not surjective - yet both sets are bijective.